# CurrentSrc missing from Google Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using image srcset on a WordPress theme that I'm developing.

Here's what's pushed out on the front-end:

```html
<img
    src="image.jpg"
    sizes="(max-width:1000px) 100vw, 1000px"
    srcset="image.jpg 2000w, 
            image-300x169.jpg 300w,
            image-768x432.jpg 768w,
            image-1024x575.jpg 1024w"
>
```

On my last project, I was able to check which image was being served via dev tools. Depending on the viewport size, I'd inspect the element and hover my cursor over the image tag. Chrome would then display a hover over with `currentsrc:`.

This is no longer working within dev tools.

Has Chrome moved this feature else where or is this a bug?

I'm using the latest version: 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on Mac OSX Yosemite (10.10.5).

Comment: Apparently, a bug, because it works in Chrome 58 canary which you can install separately.

Comment: I salute you sir, thank you. I wasn't even aware of Chrome Canary. I can confirm that this is a bug in Chrome 56 and currentsrc returns in Chrome Canary. Please set this as your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Click on the element in dev tool and you can find currentSrc in Properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900438/6574043